# Fullcalendar on click alert selected date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar. I want that if i double click on any date on calender it should provide me the selected date in form of "2013-12-10".

Here is my current code for this event:

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

var getSelectedDate = date.getFullYear()+'-'+date.getMonth()+'-'+date.getDate();

alert(getSelectedDate );

},
```

The problem with this code is, its returning wrong month.

Comment: you get right month by `date.getMonth()+1`. because `getMonth` return index of month. like 0 = JAN,1 = FEB and so on 11 = DEC.

Comment: So what if it is Jan? Ur Solution will add 
+1 to 0 in case of Jan, and it will return Feb

Comment: this is just for display purpose so if you want to display january in numeric you will use "1" and that is `getMonth() + 1`

Answer (score 1):

The month starts with 0, i.e. January is 0, Did you considered this fact?

Reference
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/month/

Thank you